# Recycling Through an Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on creating a weather forecast web-app. I've been having difficulty assigning the days of the week to the upcoming forecast. As of now, when I cycle though the array the loop counts up to 6 (Saturday), and the continues to count 7, 8, 9, 10... and so on. I need to find a way to reset this loop so after 6, it starts back at 0 (Sunday). I know the solution to this should be simple, but I can't seem to see it. This is my attempt so far...

```
function dayOfWeek() {
   var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
   var today = new Date().getDay();

   if (today === 6) {
     today = 0;
   }

   for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   console.log(today + i);
   }
  }

dayOfWeek()

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator (`%`) like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log((today + i) % 7);
}
```

The modulo operator returns the *remainder* of a division operation between the two operands, `3 % 2` will return 1, because `3 / 2` is 1 and **1** half.

Similarly, 9 % 7 will return `2` because the result is 1 and **2** sevenths.

This allows you to cycle through the array as many times as you want, you just modulo the array's length.

Comment: `1 and 1 half.`, `1 and 2 sevenths` that's not actually the remainder that you get - using integer division you don't _have_ any rational numbers `7 % 3` will not produce "two and one third" it produces the number `2` (because `2 * 3 = 6` and you cannot fit any more `3`s into a `7`) and the remainder is `1` derived by `7 (base amount) - 6 (how many divisors "fit" in the base number) = 1 (what remains undivided)`

Comment: 7 % 3 is 1 because the result of division *is* 2 and 1 third, though... Even if JS has no accurate way of representing that number. Also my way is slightly simpler to explain to a beginner, even if not 100% accurate.

Comment: No, integer division does not have any fractions, as I said. There is no "one third" left. In fact, it's not even "easier" for beginners, considering this is taught in schools _before_ integers are introduced. Children are able to calculate remainders before they even know what "one third" means, for it is very, very simple - it is literally in the name - what is the number that _remains_ after you divide by something. If you already have one third, that's already _divided_ by the number, it doesn't _remain_ to be divided.

Comment: @vlaz This is JavaScript, there's only one Number type, and it's not integer. As for the remainder, that's the first thing I said about the modulo operator, and the examples followed. Also, if you feel my explanation to be insufficient despite this conversation, feel free to vote down and post an answer of your own.

Comment: I don't want incorrect terminology to be used. In integer division, you get _integers_ as the name implies. Yes, JS does not have an integer type but that is irrelevant in this case as we are talking about a mathematical operation. Similarly, JS does not have a "rational number" type, hence you cannot even claim that "one third" is somehow the remainder, since 1. it doesn't fit the numeric type that JS uses 2. it is not the product that the modulo operator produces. I have no idea why you insist so much on using the wrong terms when they are clearly and objectively defined.